# How to convert String to Boolean in Java, but to treat null differently than false?

Tags: java, boolean

I was wondering if there is a straightforward way (one-line, without creating a function) to convert `String` to `Boolean` in Java, but in a way that `Boolean` is `null` if `String` is `null`.

If I see it correctly, all of the methods from the `Boolean` class are returning `false` if the input string is `null`. Why is that?

Why is it better that `Boolean.valueOf(String s)` returns `false` in the case of `s` being `null`, rather than returning `null`?

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(s).map(Boolean::valueOf).orElse(null)` is an alternative. Mainly useful if your value is already wrapped in an Optional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is it better that `Boolean.valueOf(String s)` returns `false` in the case of `s` being `null`, rather than returning `null`?

It is a matter of opinion, and (to be frank) pointless to ask ... unless you happen to be designing your own language and runtime libraries.  The design decision was made more than 20 years ago, and there is zero chance that it will be changed while the language is called "Java".

The javadocs for `Boolean.valueOf(String)`   don't offer any clues as to why the designers designed it this way.

However, it is clear that the behavior of `Boolean.valueOf(String)` is **inconsistent** with the behavior of `valueOf(String)` for the other primitive wrapper classes.  For example `Integer.valueOf(String)` throws `NumberFormatException` if the string argument is `null`.  So it is possible that the real explanation is that the `Boolean.valueOf(String)` semantics are just an unfortunate anomaly that is the result of an oversight that occurred in the rush to release Java 1.0.

However, that is speculation.  For a real answer you would need to consult relevant internal Sun / Oracle documentary sources (if they still exist) and / or talk to someone on the original Java team (if they can still remember).

Comment: I have a favorite speculation for this: `Boolean.getBoolean`, that pinnacle of API perversion clearly dating from the earliest of early Java, actually has good reason to return `false` for a missing system property. Naturally, it relies internally on the API of `Boolean.parseBoolean`..

Answer (score 7):

> Why is it better that `Boolean.valueOf(String s)` returns `false` in the case of `s` being `null`, rather than returning `null`?

Because out the build-in feature in Java, called *autoboxing*.

Let's suppose that `Boolean.valueOf(String s)` **was** actually returning `null`, when `s` is `null`. Then, the following statement would be throwing `NullPointerException`, because `null` cannot be assigned to a primitive:

```
boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(null);
```

Comment: Nice point. But why does `Integer.parseInt(null)` throw `NumberFormatException(null)` - doesn't autoboxing also apply there?

Comment: @vikingsteve where is the auto-boxing in this case?

Comment: @vikingsteve: It could be argued that a null String represents a false value for most uses. But what integer number should a null String represent? Also, as Peter correctly pointed out, Integer.parseInt already returns an int, not an Integer.

Comment: If you need a `boolean` from a `String`, then you'll use `Boolean.parseBoolean`, not `valueOf`. How could a misguided idiom, which goes through the redundant process of boxing followed by immediate unboxing, justify any API design decision?

Comment: On a wider note, most of the JDK API is designed around the fail-fast principle, forcing the client to make explicit null-checks everywhere instead of returning sensible defaults. The justification of the opposite in this one case would require much more elaboration.

Comment: I guess we are going into subjective opinion here, but if you were to design `Boolean.valueOf()` for `null` arguments, and given the state of the rest of the core api, Marko would you have it return null, return false or throw `IllegalArgumentExecption` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve It would be in the spirit of the JDK to throw a `NullPointerException` and force the client to implement an explicit `null`-sentinel policy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator :

```
String s = ...
Boolean b = s != null ? Boolean.valueOf(s) : null;
```

Comment: And then, the last part of the question, why is the actualy functionality of `Boolean.valueOf()` better than if it returned null?